# import multifile at different table

Tags: mysql, file-io

idea :

> LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\MyTextFile'
>   INTO TABLE myDatabase.MyTable
>   FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'

problem came with :
i have 2 file :
1.txt for table 123
2.txt for table abc

how to load that data ?

Comment: What's the actual problem? Can't you just run `LOAD DATA INFILE` once for each file/table?

Comment: i mean if i have more than 10 file for 10 tables

and .... yes i can load it for each file/table